# Heroku build failing - Sprockets::ArgumentError: require_tree argument must be a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sprockets

I'm trying to push my Rails 3.2 app up to Heroku, but the push gets rejected because Sprockets can't find the directory I'm referencing with require_tree.

In *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/extender/
```

The error portion of the build looks like:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sprockets::ArgumentError: require_tree argument must be a directory
(in /tmp/.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js:1)
```

As I understand it items under `vendor/assets/` should be available as though they were under `app/assets/`, but I can't seem to get that to work and the way I'm doing it above works locally, so I'm running with it.

What I don't understand is why **this works locally but not when pushing to Heroku**. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: for some reason my `.gitignore` was ignoring `/vendor`.

Answer (score 0):

*app/assets/javascripts* and *vendor/assets/javascripts* get merged into the same level, so you should `require_tree extender` if *vendor/assets/javascripts/extender/* exists.

You shouldn't go have to do *../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/*. See **Search Paths** in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: Hey Leito! Thanks for the response. I'm aware of Search Paths, but I'm attempting a different structure. All I'm really curious about is why it's not working on Heroku.

Comment: I'm glad you find the solution, mark your answer as such, so others can easily see what you did.

Comment: Have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer :)